# java negator operator

Tags: java

Hi i'm trying to use a negator operator in java to try and change a negative amount inputted by a user to the same number but just as a positive. Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @larsman, all the solutions I can think of work the same for both. What did you have in mind which would work for one but not the other?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) == Integer.MIN_VALUE` and similarly for `long`.

Comment: This is true, but it has no simple solution. The tip here would be to avoid the user entering -2147483648 for int or -9223372036854775808 for long.  For double you definitively want to avoid parsing 2.2250738585072012e-308 (positive or negative)  If you are worried about these it may be best to handle these individually.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [Math.abs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28double%29). In case you are desperately bored: [Absolute Value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteValue.html). Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The "negator operator" is the the same as the "unary minus".

Just as in math, `-` kan represent binary minus "`a - b`" and unary minus, "`-a`".

If your user inputs a negative number, you can "negate" the value by doing

```
input = -input;
```

or

```
input *= -1;
```

---

As @nc3b suggests, you could use

```
input = Math.abs(input);
```

which would correspond to

```
if (input < 0)
    input = -input;
```

or

```
input = input < 0 ? -input : input;
```